# ElasticSearch and Redis Remote Servers

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, redis

I deployed a Laravel application on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.

I want to incorporate caching with Redis as my cache driver as well as Elasticsearch.

I managed to run these 2 features locally (redis on port 6379 and elasticsearch on 9200),
but now I want them to run on remote servers and I simply specify their endpoints in my .env file.

Can anyone let me know how I can obtain remote URLs for Redis and Elasticsearch?

***Update:***
I found out that Heruko offers the ability to create a Redis instance and thereby one can obtain a URL for Redis. I presume a similar thing is for Elasticsearch.

If this is not the right way to do so, please let me know how it works

Comment: "how I can obtain remote URLs for Redis and Elasticsearch?" You would first need to create those remote servers before you could obtain the URLs for those servers. What have you actually done so far in that regard?

Comment: I mean, I was wondering if there is a way to use, for example, to use a remote Redis service and connect to it through a URL. Currently I am running it locally. 

 I found out that Heruko offers the ability to create a Redis instance and thereby one can obtain a URL for Redis. I presume a similar thing is for Elasticsearch

Comment: Yes that is possible for pretty much every type of service that exists.